# how to aggregate all values in a group_by by using `sqlalchemy core`

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using `sqlalchemy core` for a Python project, Here is DDL:

```
DOMAIN = Table(
    "domain",
    METADATA,
    Column("id", BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("watch_id", String, index=True),
)
ESCALATION = Table(
    "escalation",
    METADATA,
    Column("id", BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("domain_id", BigInteger, ForeignKey("domain.id")),
    Column("escalation_type", String),
)
```

There are 3 types of `escalation_type` for each of domain. Now I need to write a function that given a watch_id, it returns a list of dictionaries for that specific watchlist_id, each dictionary being a domain  with a list that includes all escalation types for that domain. this function also need to support pagination. something like this as a result:

```
[{"domain":"example_1.com", "escalation": ["type-A", "type-B"]},
 {"domain":"example_2.com", "escalation": ["type-A"],
 {"domain":"example_3.com", "escalation": ["type-A", "type-B", "type-C]},
 {"domain":"example_4.com", "escalation": []},
 ...]
```

I think I can join these two tables, and then group_by domain_id(in order to support pagination), but I don't know how I can add all escalation types to a list which is added to the dict for that domain - my understanding there is no such aggregation function that can do that. Please let me know if there is any `sqlalchemy` trick that can do that.

someone points that this can be done by `selectinloading()`, after some search, it seems to me that that's a function only available for `sqlalchemy ORM` but we're using `sqlalchemy core`. I would wish there were something like `selectinloading()` in `core` that I could use it easily to solve this.

Please let me know any idea or solution on this. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using PostgreSQL, there's `array_agg()`, and other DBMS can pull off something of the kind using `string_agg()` or equivalent, but that then requires some Python side processing.